# How to insert soap:Body content as a child to another tag

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have the following soap:body

```
<soapenv:Body>
   <Message>
      <Context>
         <id>10</id>
         <subject>sub10</subject>
         <body>body10</body>
      </Context>
   </Message>
</soapenv:Body>
```

But I need to insert the content inside `<SendMessageRequest>` tag before sending to a request:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <SendMessageRequest>
       <Message>
          <Context>
             <id>10</id>
             <subject>sub10</subject>
             <body>body10</body>
          </Context>
       </Message>
    </SendMessageRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I'm using the `Enrich Mediator`, but not figured out how to do this...
Here the code I'm trying:

```
<enrich>
    <source type="body"/>
    <target action="child" type="custom" xpath="SendMessageRequest"/>
</enrich>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly add an intermediate element. That is one that wraps your current content. Instead you can store your content-to-be-wrapped in a property. Note the use of the `$body` xpath variable (courtesy of the [`SynapseXPath`](http://synapse.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/synapse/util/xpath/SynapseXPath.html) class), which refers to the soap body element regardless of used soap version.

```
<property name="payload" expression="$body/*[1]" type="OM"/>
```

Then use the `PayloadFactory` mediator to construct your new request stub:

```
<payloadFactory>
  <format>
    <SendMessageRequest xmlns=""/>
  </format>
  <args/>
</payloadFactory>
```

Subsequently you can enrich your former content into the newly created payload.

```
<enrich>
  <source clone="true" property="payload" type="property"/>
  <target action="child" type="custom" xpath="$body/SendMessageRequest"/>
</enrich>
```

Comment: Thanks Kallja. Complementing... in the Enrich target, the attribute `type="body"` is needed.